# Parse create user example not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a registration screen for a new web project I'm working on. It didn't seem to be working so I tried out just using the basic create user example on Parse.com

```
function register()
{
  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.set("username", "my name");
  user.set("password", "my pass");
  user.set("email", "email@example.com");


  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });

}
```

Every time the call gets made I get this error...

[image]

Any ideas would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the specifics about Error codes for Parse here : https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#errors

100 is "ConnectionFailed". Seems like you (or at least your app ^^) has a problem connecting to Parse servers...

Hope it helps.

(on another note, you should edit your first post instead of answering if you want to add infos, follow-ups etc to your question ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the database... turns out it was working but still throwing the error state. Guess I just have to check specific errors for now